# How to solve TypeError:'type' object is not subscriptable in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to generate some random numbers, put them in a list and write them in a text file. 
For example, want to generate random numbers from 1 to 20, but I want 50 outputs from it. So repetitions are allowed.

My code is:

```
r= list[random.randrange(1,20,50)]  
L2= []
for item in r:
    t= basic_delay + 2*basic_jitter*item - basic_jitter
    L2.append(str(t))

for item in L2:
    file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

after execution I am getting the error message:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do now?

Comment: i used that, but then another error is shown- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: Yes because you are trying to use `list` on an integer. By the way `random.randrange(1, 20, 50)` will always give you `1`. I think you meant to do `r = [random.randrange(1,21) for i in range(50)]`

Comment: You might want to read up on the docs for `random`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange